# Face was broken while zoom in

Tags: modeling, objects

[image]
Does anyone knows what happen with my model ?
Why the face was broken while zoom in?

[image]

Comment: I think this is because while zooming, the view gets inside the model. Try to switch to ortho view (it will still happen but will be less "surprising")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's due to the ***camera clipping*** settings. Set the clip's ***Start*** value to ***0.001*** and it may solve your problem.
[image]